# line_descriptor.hpp is included, but KeyLine and also BinaryDescriptor are still undefined

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I have been using OpenCV 3.0 that are combined with the extra modules using CMake 3.5. I am using Visual Studio 2012 32bit as my IDE.

However, i cannot seem to use both KeyLine and also BinaryDescriptor. They give me error which is "identifier KeyLine is undefined". I have set the Paths and also library setting.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/line_descriptor.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main( void ) {
    Ptr<BinaryDescriptor> bd = BinaryDescriptor::createBinaryDescriptor();// this line gives error
    vector<KeyLine> lines; // same as this
}
```

I have tried the other header, for instance the tracking.hpp. I am able to define:

```
Ptr<Tracker> tkr;
```

Without having the Tracker giving me error.

Anyone know if the error is caused during CMake process or i miss out something?

Comment: Are you linking OpenCV library in? Show us your CMake code.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by CMake code?

I followed the steps in this website in merging the OpenCV extra module.

https://putuyuwono.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/building-and-installing-opencv-3-0-on-windows-7-64-bit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same problem, and stumbled upon your question.

The answer I just found out is you have to add,

```
using namespace line_descriptor;
```

at the top along with cv namespace.Got this hint from line_descriptor.hpp source code.